# How to show not filtered data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to power bi, and this question might be a common question and already answered, but I didn't find any precise solution.

I have two tables; **"Dates"** and **"Accounts"**.

1. **Dates** table has only one column: **"Date"**(date type). It has only date value, which is day based.
2. **Accounts** table has two columns; **Name**(text type) and **CreatedDate**(date dypttype).

In my power bi model, there is a relationship(*many to one, single, active*) between **Dates.Date** and **Accounts.CreatedDate** columns.

---

I want to show account names that except the filtered ones. For example, my **Accounts** table look like this:

| Name | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- |
| A Company | 2020-01-01 |
| B Company | 2020-12-15 |
| C Company | 2021-03-03 |
| D Company | 2019-05-27 |

I have a slicer and use **Dates.Date** as It's field.

[image: Slicer With Date Field]

When I filtered my data as last 1 year (2020-08-18 - 2021-08-18), I want to show the data which is not filtered. I want to see this:

| Name | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- |
| A Company | 2020-01-01 |
| D Company | 2019-05-27 |

How to show the data which is not filtered?

Comment: I really hope this is not possible. If you are new to Power BI, stick to it's standard behaviour and don't confuse yourself and others.

Comment: I didn't like this either, but they literally asked me to do this whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter `Measure` like following

```
    _filter:= 
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    /* t1 = what is value selected ?*/
    CONVERT ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Calendar_Date] ), INTEGER ) = BLANK ()   
    /* t2=what is the max CreatedDate value visble in the filter context*/
    /*if t1 and t2 both blank then return -999 else return t1-t2 which should be 0*/
        && CONVERT ( MAX ( tbl[CreatedDate] ), INTEGER ) = BLANK (), -999, 
    CONVERT ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Calendar_Date] ), INTEGER )
        - CONVERT ( MAX ( tbl[CreatedDate] ), INTEGER )
)
```

[image: SOlution]